# cpp program multi-file input using fstream

Tags: c++, arrays, file, edit, filestream

I would like to ask about inputing more than one file or about the easiest way how to put filenames to some queue.
This files are about edit.

I have,  let me say,  100 txt files and for each one I wanted to open it,  find something and and save it.

I have functions/methods for each operation.

But I run into problem loading files into program.  I made it for five or less files.

Process is.  Program asked me for file name in program root directory or full path to file 
for example C/myfile.txt

after pressing enter executes.

unfortunately bad thing happened and I have to do 100 files per day.  So I know in C# is possible to make open file dialog -  multiple file load...

In this program,  I was thinking about doing static array of strings and for each make a for cycle with iterration.

but I have no idea what is the easier way how to load this strings (filenames)  into this array.

I read something on msdn but it looks so complicated for me.

Can someone help?  Program is just for me and I don't want to set too many things. It is possible? 
what is the less or minimalistic part of code I must use -  add to my program?

example of result I want 
array[0] = C/text. txt
array[1] = C/texta. txt
...
array[50] = C/textdhsjfk. txt

maybe it is not so easy as I think,  maybe yes.

But I have no support in this major... So I only tried to find something on the interent and I am not sure about the result I have found.

Thank you for time and willing to help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Loops and iterators are a good choice.  The `std::string` container is also appropriate.

Comment: Are you trying to open and process each file in a directory or a list of files (like stored in a file)?

Comment: my program runs in cmd style So I need drag and drop each file here... I would like to replace drag and drop system by something different.  I read about open file dialog but I am not sure if it is suitable and not too complicated for me. I look for easiest way how to load paths to files somewhere (Array)  and store them and for each process the application

Comment: When you select multiple files, then drag them into a console based program, Windows places each file as a separate argument / parameter to the program.  You'll need to copy the program's arguments into a container.

Comment: So,  what I need is just create array of strings?  and set cin function to it?

Comment: The main function has some parameters, such as `int main(int argument_count, char * argument_list[])`.  The parameter `argument_list` is an array of pointers to all those folder names that were dragged to your program.  So, `argument_list[0]` is the name of the program, `argument_list[1]` is the first parameter, `argument_list[2]` is the second argument and so on.  The first argument, `argument_count`, is the number of parameters passed to your program.

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand I suppose. Could you explain it closer ? Or more "noobfully" for me ?

But I tried to do this: 
using system with which I can use cmd commands I tried to :

char[] command = " DIR D:\  /s /b " ;
cout << system(command);

That prints for me file names of files stored in certain folder . 

Can I somehow use this system command for loading all filenames inside folder to some array ??? or is it a easier way ???

thank you

Answer (score 0):

A loop and a container look like good things to use:

```
static const char filenames[] =
{
  "C:\\Fred\\file1.txt", "c:\\Fred\\file2.txt", "c:\\Barney\\file1.txt",
};
static const unsigned int quantity_of_files =
    sizeof(filenames) / sizeof(filenames[0]);

//...
for (unsigned int i = 0u; i < quantity_of_files; ++i)
{
  std::ifstream input_stream(filenames[i]);
  Process_Input_Stream(input_stream);
  input_stream.close();
}
```

The task is to get the code working correctly and robust, then worry about performance.

*Note:  The program is set up so that file names can be added to the array without having to change or retest the code.*

Comment: i suppose your solution means I have to load file one by one.  I wanted to avoid this situation and put all 100+ filenames inside a array at once...  each time ( now i know)  i will have up to 110 files = 110 filenames at once to load...  but i am not sure if it is possible...  like in c# wit open file dialog...

Comment: Putting file names into an array is quite different than opening them.  Since the OS file system API is not parallel, you can only open one at a time.  There are no bulk file opening functions in Linux nor Windows.